# Flask - отключение сортировки

Tags: python, json, flask

В данном коде, return выводит нам значение переменных в json

```
    @app.route('/enc_config', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def enc_config():
    global video_fmt
    global img_fmt
    global record_file
    global img_file
    global resolution_h
    global resolution_w
    global img_effect
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(video=video_fmt, image=img_fmt, record=record_file, imgfile=img_file, width=resolution_w, height=resolution_h,)
    else:
        video_fmt = request.form['video_fmt']
        img_fmt = request.form['img_fmt']
    return jsonify(video=video_fmt, image=img_fmt, record=record_file, imgfile=img_file, width=resolution_w, height=resolution_h,)
```

к сожалению показывает он их не в таком порядке как они написаны а, пишет их согласно алфовиту. Как отключить эту функцию?

Comment: в сторону: не используйте `global`, если вы переменные только на чтение используете (как в коде в вопросе). `global` бесполезно тут для всех переменных кроме `video_fmt`, `img_fmt`. Можно в одну строчку писать `global video_fmt, img_fmt`. В целом лучше ограничить использование глобальных переменных. Для хранения конфигурации, вероятно простая база-данных подойдёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Кратко**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d['video'] = 1
>>> d['image'] = 2
>>> d['record'] = 3
>>> d['imgfile'] = 4
>>> d['width'] = 5
>>> d['height'] = 6
>>> jsonify(d)
'{"video": 1, "image": 2, "record": 3, "imgfile": 4, "width": 5, "height": 6}'
```

**Подробно**

Если посмотреть на исходный код функции [`jsonify`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/json.py#L201), можно увидеть, что она передаёт свои аргументы прямо в `json.dumps`. Причём передаёт их в виде словаря, то есть, объекта, не гарантирующего порядок итерации элементов. Если почитать [документацию](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) `json.dumps`, то становится ясно, что она может сортировать ключи в получившемся JSON, но только если передать ей в качестве агрумента `sort_keys=True`. Как видно из [исходного кода](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/json.py#L266), функция `jsonify` этого не делает. Почему у вас ключи в алфавитном порядке? Вам просто повезло. Смотрите:

```
>>> json.dumps({'video':1,'image':2,'record':3,'imgfile':4,'width':5,'height':6})
'{"height": 6, "imgfile": 4, "image": 2, "record": 3, "video": 1, "width": 5}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
'{"b": 2, "c": 3, "a": 1}'
>>> json.dumps({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'
```

Ваш набор ключей представился во внутренней структуре словаря именно в таком порядке. Если вы хотите, чтобы словарь запоминал порядок вставки ключей, используйте класс [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Но учтите, он запоминает именно порядок вставки элементов. Если вы создадите `OrderedDict` из существующего словаря (`d = OrderedDict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})`), порядок ключей не сохранится.

Comment: а возможно выключить сортировку без использования словаря как в кратком описании?  если я правильно понял то `return jsonify({video=video_fmt, image=img_fmt, record=record_file, imgfile=img_file, width=resolution_w, height=resolution_h} sort_keys=True)` должен выводить в таком порядке как прописано в самом коде?

Comment: Ещё раз: никакой сортировки нет, вам просто (не)повезло. Стандартный словарь никогда не гарантирует порядок итерации ключей. Нет вообще никакой возможности заставить словарь перебирать ключи именно в том порядке, в котором они заданы в коде. Только `OrderedDict`, только хардкор. Существует [PEP 0468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/), предлагающий сохранять `**kwargs` в `OrderedDict`, но дальше обсуждения дело пока не зашло.

Comment: @Insider: даже если бы python сохранял порядок именованных параметров при вызове функции (как это например делает pypy-реализация Питона, если я не ошибаюсь), *поля в JSON не имеют заданного порядка* (некоторые парсеры могут сохранять порядок: `json.loads(json_text, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)` и [в обратную сторону](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23820416/4279), но стандарт JSON этого не требует.